# LEDA-6.3 library

Tags: c++, graphics, ubuntu

I am a leda-6.3 library user.

I used graphwin to manipulate and display graphs, but I found that references 
to graphwin methods are undefined while compiling the code although they 
are declared in the LEDA/incl/LEDA/graphics/graphwin.h

So I think it is a problem of object file.

```
#include <LEDA/graphics/graphwin.h>
#include <LEDA/graph/graph_alg.h>

using namespace leda;

int main()
{  
GraphWin gw("LEDA Graph Editor");
node u=gw.new_node(point(100,100));
node v=gw.new_node(point(100,200));
gw.new_edge(u,v);

gw.display();
gw.get_window().read_mouse();

graph& G=gw.get_graph();
G.new_node();
gw.get_window().read_mouse();

gw.update_graph();
gw.get_window().read_mouse();

return 0;
}
```

> compilation: g++  -I$LEDAROOT/incl -L$LEDAROOT gw.cpp -lleda -lX11 -lm -o gw

ERROR :

```
/tmp/ccVHyRbL.o: In function `main':
gw.cpp:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `leda::GraphWin::GraphWin(char const*)'
gw.cpp:(.text+0x58): undefined reference to `leda::GraphWin::new_node(leda::point const&)'
gw.cpp:(.text+0xc6): undefined reference to `leda::GraphWin::new_node(leda::point const&)'
gw.cpp:(.text+0x11c): undefined reference to `leda::GraphWin::new_edge(leda::node_struct*, leda::node_struct*)'
gw.cpp:(.text+0x128): undefined reference to `leda::GraphWin::display()'
gw.cpp:(.text+0x17e): undefined reference to `leda::GraphWin::update_graph()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Hi Kamel, welcome to SO. Just a couple of hints. Please give your post an appropriate title and flags. And if you have errors, please include the relevant ones into your post. And in this case you might want to tell what your development environment is and how you compile your program. Especially with regards to linking.

Answer (score 0):

Which edition of LEDA are you using?
Please consider that free edition of LEDA does not contain GraphWin.
So, it dos not contain GraphWin libraries, which results to getting such errors while compiling your program.